# Bash: Get Key, without Colon, While Looping YAML Booleans

Tags: bash

I've got a YAML data file:

```yaml
alabama: false
arizona: true
arkansas: true
...
```

I need to loop this data checking for the states with `true` values.

```sh
while read state value; do
  if [[ "$value" = *'true'* ]]; then
    echo "$state"
  fi
done
```

This returns the state name with the colon, e.g. `arizona:`. How do I get only the state name, e.g. `arizona`?

Comment: `while IFS=': ' read state value; do`, if all you want to do is strip `:`s

Comment: ...that said, the better approach is to use a real YAML parser. This same data could also be written as `{"alabama": false, "arizona": true, "arkansas": true}` all on one line, and it'd be perfectly legal YAML. A real parser will recognize it both ways; a hand-rolled one won't.

Comment: See for example the two (independent, mutually-incompatible) tools named `yq`, both of which aim to be an equivalent to `jq` for yaml. (One is a wrapper and so supports real jq syntax; the other is just inspired-by and not actually compatible). We have lots of Q&A entries showing how to parse JSON from bash with jq; the general approaches given in those answers will work with a yq-esque tool as well.

Comment: (Similarly, there are a lot of answers showing how to use the Python `json` module from bash; one can use one of the available Python YAML modules the same way).

Comment: I second @CharlesDuffy there ... when complex processing is needed, a Python script might be much better than writing obscure incantations.

Comment: Charles, the `IFS=': '` option worked perfectly. Thanks for this. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`read` itself can strip out the `:`s, if you add them to `IFS` (the variable providing a list of field-separator characters).

Thus:

```
while IFS=': ' read -r state value; do
  if [[ "$value" = *'true'* ]]; then
    echo "$state"
  fi
done
```

That said, I don't recommend using shell scripts to parse YAML directly -- using a real YAML parser (whether via a tool such as `yq`, or a YAML library for Python) to translate data into a format optimized for easy processing will generally yield more robust results.

Answer (score 0):

Trim the colon off the `$state` variable:

```
while read state value; do
  if [[ "$value" = *'true'* ]]; then
    echo "$state" | tr -d ':'
  fi
done
```

Comment: Much more efficient to refer to `"${state//:/}"` to remove `:`s. `echo "$state" | tr -d ':'` is surprisingly inefficient -- it forks off two subprocesses, and then `exec`s the separate binary `/usr/bin/tr` from one of them. Orders of magnitude faster, for short strings, to just use the shell's built-in string manipulation primitives.

Comment: There is, in fact, more than one way to skin a cat.

Comment: Indeed so. That said, some of those are objectively better than others. As a teaching resource, we should care.

Comment: I have rarely encountered a dataset in which it matters that much.  And when it does, it is objectively better to not use a shell script.

Comment: It's less the dataset, and more the context of use. If someone puts `echo "$state" | tr -d :` inside a tight loop, the overhead adds up very quickly. Iterating over a maildir of 10,000-20,000 files and operating on their names is a classic example of where I've seen that kind of practice bite people while doing typical sysadmin/ops work (being a scenario where bash use is typical/common).

Comment: Here, you're doing a `while read` loop, so you're starting a new copy of `tr` (plus two transient subshells) for every line read. Doesn't have to be a very long file for the overhead to matter in that context.

Comment: See ideone.com/YKOlEL for some concrete numbers, benchmarking both approaches.